# Watch folder and print without intervention

Tags: windows-7

I want to watch a folder that may receive Word or PDF files, print them, and delete the files.

I don't know how to do this without dialogs popping up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to write a program that would watch the directory and invoke Word or a PDF library/viewer as appropriate. This really isn't built in functionality within the OS.